# Use a Griffin Powermate to control the Toslink output of my Mac

Tags: audio

I'm using a Mac mini as a media player. This is linked to my sound system via Toslink, so the system volume setting is locked.

Until recently, most of my media was played via VLC, which has its own volume controls that are easily controlled by the Powermate.
Recently though I've started to view more media via Firefox. The volume controls on a webpage are usually not controllable via keyboard shortcuts, so I'm left without usable volume controls.
E.g. when viewing Apple TV+ through the browser, I have to use the mouse to drag the volume slider, with the drawback that annyoing controls are plastered over the middle of the video.

I've looked at Rogue Amoeba's SoundSource, but that doesn't seem to have a way to control volume when that app is not the foreground app.

Is there a way to adjust the volume of a video stream in Firefox via the Powermate (or via keyboard shortcuts, which I can generate using Keyboard Maestro)?

Comment: I doubt you’ll find anything. The main issue here is how is this software/hardware “widget”, for lack of a better word, supposed to know *which* browser process you want to control volume for especially when each browser window/tab is a discrete process which allows  simultaneous processes to play audio/video?

Comment: SoundSource works on the “frontmost” window because it is the one most likely you want to control and this is how GUI elements like web page audio is controlled.

Comment: The Powermate USB was discontinued back in 2018 and is not designed to work past High Sierra for Mac or Vista for Windows. From my memory of the product, you can only use it to interact with the frontmost application. I don't believe it can interact with controls running in a browser window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem consists of 2 parts:

1. being able to control the output volume when a digital output is used. VLC demonstrates that in-app volume controls work.
2. controlling the volume through something other than a mouse that operates an on-screen slider.

There are several applications that give you per-app volume controls in MacOS.

- SoundSource. This has an option 'Super volume keys' that should allow you to control the volume of an output device that ordinarily does not have a volume control. When I switch this on, the volume keys on my keyboard can control the Toslink output. I was unable to get this to work with my Powermate. The Powermate has an option to send 'Volume Up/Down' signals directly, but that does not get picked up by this setup. So this does not work for my situation.
- SoundControl. This has options to set keyboard shortcuts for increasing/decreasing the volume in any application. I can bind this to the existing keyboard shortcuts emitted by the Powermate, and get a working solution.

So yes, this is possible. There is one limitation: Griffin has discontinued the PowerMate, and it's not supported directly in recent MacOS releases. There are reports that USB Overdrive supports the PowerMate, I haven't been able to verify that yet.